# Custom USB driver for MCU data

Tags: java, usb, driver, microcontroller

I have a cross platform JAVA program which will need data from a MCU plugged into the USB.
I need a general overview of how this can be accomplished.
Is it possible to write a USB driver that will sling the incoming USB data onto a local socket port, which I can then connect to from within Java?
Is there a better alternative to using a Virtual COM Port driver?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Another option is an USB HID driver.

Comment: Hi Kenny, is there an advantage to going with an HID driver?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a simple project in which I have developed a customized USB communication through a Virtual COM (CDC).This project is based on a 8-bits microcontroller - particularly MC9S08JS family - working on CodeWarrior Development Studio 10.3.
I attach two zip files. One of them is the complete CodeWarrior project and the other is the USB CDC driver.Files are working properly, and obviously they are totally safe. Users only have to add their routines to send and receive data through endpoints functions.

Links:

1- [CodeWarrior project](https://mega.co.nz/#!bI02XZjJ!GcbKz250W6jiJq1POD06G0hi_o5EOjgtt6v7Ez8nfhA).

2- [USB CDC driver](https://mega.co.nz/#!6B9hHRRC!VY6tDEKVyFCaeakRrDP2h2xuWA5_sRrdmh52AqKDQjg).

I really hope that it can help you. Please, let me know if you have any question.

Best regards,
Mauricio.

Answer (score 0):

Look into developing a CDC driver or implementing an FTDI chip. The later being much easier but if you're looking at reducing product cost, having your own USB stack is invaluable. In either case, your device will appear as a virtual comm port as you requested and be easily accessible as a regular comm port.

A good place to start would be reviewing the Freescale USB stack, v4.1.1. There are working examples for MSD, CDC, HID, and a slew of other classes to help get you going. If you're not using Freescale micros your mileage may vary but it's still worth reading.

Lastly, from my experience I found serial port access a little tricky for cross-platform Java. I used an RXTX branch from Cloudhopper but I've heard good things about https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/.

Good luck!